# How can I get the animation to run until I submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The script that I put is not working, and I cant get why.
I want the animation to run until I submit the form, the animation is suppose to take the whole form and move it down.

The animation is taking place when I load the page, but I want it to run until I click on submit.

The animation is taking place when I load the page, but I want it to run until I click on submit.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").on('click', function(){
         $("#div1").addclass('animation');
    })
});
```

```css
.animation {
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove 10s;
}
@keyframes mymove {
from {
top: 0px;
}
to {
top: 300px;
}
}
.form2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
<title>Comements</title>

<body>
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3 font-weight-bolder">Comments</h3>
<div  class="container pt-5" >
  
  <div id="div1" class="d-flex justify-content-center container-sm p-4">
    <form  class="form1" >
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputName">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputLastName1">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno"  id="apellido_paterno" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email"  required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="rating">Rating</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="rating_stars"  required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
            <option>1 star</option>
            <option>2 stars</option>
            <option>3 stars</option>
            <option>4 stars</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center  p-3 ">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md font-weight-normal" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <div class="p-4"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: How about using `animation: [animation-name] [animation length] infinite` ?

Comment: Mmm but I dont want the animation to be infinite, just when I click the submit button.

Comment: You could remove the class that creates the animation when the submit button is clicked

Comment: I did the change, but still when I click on the button submit it doesn't run the animation :(

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `removeClass` jquery function to remove animation class after clicking on submit button, [check this](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

so your code will be like :

```
  <HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Comements</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3 font-weight-bolder">Comments</h3>
    <div  class="container pt-5" >
      <div id="div1" class="d-flex justify-content-center container-sm p-4 animation">
        <form  class="form1" >
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputName">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputLastName1">Last name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno"  id="apellido_paterno" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="rating">Rating</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="rating_stars"  required>
                <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
                <option>1 estrella</option>
                <option>2 estrellas</option>
                <option>3 estrellas</option>
                <option>4 estrellas</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center  p-3 ">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md font-weight-normal" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            <div class="p-4"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .animation { position: relative; animation: mymove 10s; }
      @keyframes mymove {
        from { top: 0px; }
        to { top: 300px; }
      }
      .form2 { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#submitButton").on('click', function(){
         $("#div1").removeClass('animation');
       })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Hi, but what I need is for the animation to run when the button is clicked, not to remove it.

Comment: you said `I want it to run until I click on submit`, so if you want to run animation after submitting all you have to do is to remove the animation class from div1 and use `addClass' function in js code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spell mistake to call the function

Javascript is case sensitive. so simply

> replace <strike>addclass('animation')</strike> to addClass('animation')

At the same time all users cannot click the submit button sometimes users click the enter button to submit the form

so use the following statement to call the function

```
$("form").on('submit', function(){
     $("#div1").addClass('animation');
})
```

After fixing this two issues your following code will be

```js
$(function() {
    $("form").on('submit', function(){
         $("#div1").addClass('animation');
    })
});
```

```css
.animation {
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove 10s;
}
@keyframes mymove {
from {
top: 0px;
}
to {
top: 300px;
}
}
.form2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
<title>Comements</title>

<body>
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3 font-weight-bolder">Comments</h3>
<div  class="container pt-5" >
  
  <div id="div1" class="d-flex justify-content-center container-sm p-4">
    <form  class="form1" >
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputName">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputLastName1">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno"  id="apellido_paterno" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email"  required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="rating">Rating</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="rating_stars"  required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
            <option>1 star</option>
            <option>2 stars</option>
            <option>3 stars</option>
            <option>4 stars</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center  p-3 ">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md font-weight-normal" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <div class="p-4"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need two event handlers.

1. `click` event handler for `#submitButton` which adds `animation` class to the `#div1` when clicked.
2. The `submit` event handler, which removes the `animation` class when form gets submitted.

```js
$("#submitButton").on('click', function() {
  $("#div1").addClass('animation');
})

$('form.form1').on('submit', function() {
  $("#div1").removeClass('animation');
});
```

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 10s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
  }
}

.form2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
<title>Comements</title>

<body>
  <h3 class="text-center mt-3 font-weight-bolder">Comments</h3>
  <div class="container pt-5">

    <div id="div1" class="d-flex justify-content-center container-sm p-4">
      <form class="form1">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputLastName1">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno" id="apellido_paterno" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="rating">Rating</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="rating_stars" required>
              <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>1 star</option>
              <option>2 stars</option>
              <option>3 stars</option>
              <option>4 stars</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment">Message</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center  p-3 ">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md font-weight-normal" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
          <div class="p-4"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.8/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```